# Is $\sum_{s=n}^{m}\binom{m}{s}(x-1)^{m-s}=\sum_{s=n}^m\sum_{j=s}^m\binom{s-1}{n-1}\binom{m-s}{j-s}(x-1)^{m-j+s-n}$ an identity?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Is there any chance that this:
$$\sum_{s=n}^{m}\binom{m}{s}(x-1)^{m-s} = \sum_{s = n}^{m} \sum_{j=s}^{m}\binom{s - 1}{n - 1}\binom{m-s}{j-s} (x- 1)^{m - j +s - n}$$
is an identity? If so, what is its proof?

I observed this by solving a combinatorics problem where one of the solutions using some observations with combinatorics was $\displaystyle k^m - \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}\binom{m}{i}(k - 1)^{m - i}$ and the other was using generating functions and ended up with this formula $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^{m - n} \binom{n + i - 1}{i}(k - 1)^i \cdot k^{m - n - i}$
and somehow they are always equal for any positive integers $m \ge n$ and $k$. By some manipulations, I arrived at the identity above, but I don't know how it's true.

Comment: Seems to be wrong.    $$a(\text{n$\_$},\text{m$\_$})=\left\{\sum _{s=n}^m \binom{m}{s} (x-1)^{m-s},\sum _{s=n}^m \sum _{j=s}^m \binom{s-1}{n-1} (1-x)^{j-n} \binom{m-s}{j-s}\right\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is an identity.

Let's substitute $t=x-1$, assume that $m$ is constant and find the genfunc over $n$ for LHS:

$$ \begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n=0}^m x^n\sum\limits_{s=n}^m \binom{m}{s} t^{m-s} &=\sum\limits_{s=0}^m \binom{m}{s} t^{m-s} \sum\limits_{n=0}^s x^n \\
&= \sum\limits_{s=0}^m \binom{m}{s} t^{m-s} \frac{1-x^{s+1}}{1-x} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-x} \sum\limits_{s=0}^m \binom{m}{s} t^{m-s} (1-x^{s+1}) \\
&= \boxed{\frac{(1+t)^m - x(x+t)^m}{1-x}}
\end{align}$$

For the RHS, let's first simplify it to
$$
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{s=n}^m \sum\limits_{j=s}^m \binom{s-1}{n-1} \binom{m-s}{j-s} t^{m-j+s-n} &= \sum\limits_{s=n}^m \binom{s-1}{n-1} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-s} \binom{m-s}{j} t^{s-n} t^{m-s-j} \\
&= \sum\limits_{s=n}^m \binom{s-1}{n-1}t^{s-n} (1+t)^{m-s}.
\end{align}$$

Now let's also find the genfunc over $n$:

$$ \begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n=0}^m x^n\sum\limits_{s=n}^m \binom{s-1}{n-1}t^{s-n} (1+t)^{m-s} &= \sum\limits_{s=0}^m (1+t)^{m-s} \sum\limits_{n=0}^s \binom{s-1}{n-1} t^{s-n} x^n \\
&= (1+t)^m + \sum\limits_{s=1}^m (1+t)^{m-s} x(t+x)^{s-1} \\
&= (1+t)^m + x(1+t)^{m-1}\sum\limits_{s=0}^{m-1} \frac{(t+x)^{s}}{(1+t)^s}.
\end{align}$$

This further rewrites as
$$\begin{align}
&= (1+t)^m + x(1+t)^{m-1} \left( \frac{1-\frac{(t+x)^m}{(1+t)^m}}{1-\frac{t+x}{1+t}} \right) \\
&= (1+t)^m + x(1+t)^{m-1} \frac{(1+t)^m-(t+x)^m}{(1+t)^m - (t+x)(1+t)^{m-1}} \\
&=(1+t)^m + \frac{x(1+t)^m - x(t+x)^m}{1+t-(t+x)} \\
&=(1+t)^m + \frac{x(1+t)^m - x(t+x)^m}{1-x} = \boxed{\frac{(1+t)^m-x(x+t)^m}{1-x}}
\end{align}$$

---

**P.S.** Of course, another way would be to simply group together coefficients near $t^{m-s}$ in RHS:

$$
\sum\limits_{s=n}^m \sum\limits_{j=s}^m \binom{s-1}{n-1} \binom{m-s}{j-s} t^{m-j+s-n} = \sum\limits_{r=n}^m t^{m-r} \sum\limits_{s=n}^m \binom{s-1}{n-1} \binom{m-s}{r-n}.
$$

Now we just need to show that
$$\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{s=n}^m \binom{s-1}{n-1} \binom{m-s}{r-n} 
= \binom{m}{r},
\end{align}$$
which might or might not be easier to do directly.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for the detailed answer!
I was just wondering, you said "find the genfunc over $n$", well I don't know what that exactly means, but I understood it from the context.
Can you recommend the source from where you studied generating functions? Thanks!

Additionally, I did not understand the first equality.

Comment: I had a course in university, and read a lot of stuff on my own. Not sure I can reccomend anything definite, but I wrote some relevant articles [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/117237) and [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/103979). By genfunc over $n$, I meant multiply the expression with $x^n$ and sum for all valid values of $n$ (i.e. from $0$ to $m$). What exactly do you mean by the first equality?

Comment: The equality
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^m x^n\sum\limits_{s=n}^m \binom{m}{s} t^{m-s} =\sum\limits_{s=0}^m \binom{m}{s} t^{m-s} \sum\limits_{n=0}^s x^n$$

Digression: Btw, I just realized you're the amazing 'adamant' <3!!!!
I know you from codeforces, I'm 'Proofy' there btw, and I'm a big fan of you <3

Comment: Heh, thanks :)

I just changed the summation order...
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^m \sum\limits_{s=n}^m \dots = \sum\limits_{0 \leq n \leq s \leq m} \dots = \sum\limits_{s=0}^m \sum\limits_{n=0}^s \dots
$$

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be wrong.    $$a(\text{n$\_$},\text{m$\_$})=\left\{\sum _{s=n}^m \binom{m}{s} (x-1)^{m-s},\sum _{s=n}^m \sum _{j=s}^m \binom{s-1}{n-1} (1-x)^{j-n} \binom{m-s}{j-s}\right\}$$  yields e.g

$$ \text{a[5, 7] // FullSimplify // Expand} \longrightarrow \{15 - 35 x + 21 x^2,\  29 - 49 x + 21 x^2\}$$

Comment: Please note that it is $(x - 1)$ not $(1 - x)$ in the second formula. 

The two formulas $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^{m - n} \binom{n + i - 1}{i}(k - 1)^i \cdot k^{m - n - i}$ and $\displaystyle x^m - \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}\binom{m}{i}(x - 1)^{m - i}$ seem to give the same answer at $x = 11$ and $n = 5$ and $m =7$, so are you sure the algebra was right?

Comment: Oh, it seems I did a mistake in my algebra. I edited the correct identity above. I'm so sorry.